# How to modify small part of huge XML using Java efficiently

Tags: java, xml, dom, jaxb, sax

I need to read a huge XML file of around 1MB and modify only a small portion of it without marshaling the complete XML file.
Example:

```
<student id = "10">
    <age>11</age>
    <name>Tom</name>
    <address>Address Line 1</address>
    <phone>1234567890</phone>
    <city>NY</city>
    <zip>567890</zip>
    <postal>12345</postal>
</student>
```

From the above XML, I want to read only the address element and update, keeping other elements as is.
So above XML should become:

```
<student id = "10">
    <age>11</age>
    <name>Tom</name>
    <address>Updated Address</address>
    <phone>1234567890</phone>
    <city>NY</city>
    <zip>567890</zip>
    <postal>12345</postal>
</student>
```

However, I am getting below XML where I am loosing other elements:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<student>
    <address>Updated Address</address>
</student>
```

I am trying to use JAXB with below code:

```
 // we need a blank document to store final xml output                    
  DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();       
  DocumentBuilder docBuilder = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();                   
  Document document = docBuilder.parse("student.xml");                     
                                                                           
  // create JAXBContext which will be used to create a Binder              
  JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Student.class);                 
                                                                           
  Binder<Node> binder = jc.createBinder();                                 
                                                                           
  // set output as formatted one                                           
  binder.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);              
                                                                           
  // get xml node from the document                                        
  Node xmlNode = document.getDocumentElement();                            
                                                                           
  // Returns the updated JAXB object                                       
  Student st = (Student) binder.updateJAXB(xmlNode);                       
                                                                           
  //Update Address                    
  st.setAddress("Updated Address");                                                  
                                                                           
  // update xml node with new data                                         
  xmlNode = binder.updateXML(st);                                          
                                                                           
  // set node value to the document                                        
  document.setNodeValue(xmlNode.getNodeValue());                           
                                                                           
  // finally print the edited object on stdout                             
  TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();                
  Transformer t = tf.newTransformer();                                     
  t.transform(new DOMSource(document), new StreamResult(System.out)); 

@XmlRootElement
public class Student{

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    @XmlElement
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    String address;
   
}
```

Which Java parsing mechanism can be used to achieve this? Also which one will be more efficient in terms of memory and time ?

Comment: More efficient, brutal speed: SAX-based parsing. Anyhow, 1MB of an XML is not a huge XML. You can even use XQuery for that, which is the slower choice.

Answer (score 0):

One megabyte isn't very big these days. Really, the simplest and perfectly efficient tool for this job is XSLT. With XSLT 3.0 it's pretty close to a one-liner (plus a bit of boilerplate):

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform version="3.0">
<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
<xsl:template match="student[@id='10']/address/text()">Updated address</xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

For this task JAXB seems to introduce a lot of unnecessary complexity, in my view.